# How to print the nodes traversed in a depth first search?

Tags: c, recursion, graph, printing, depth-first-search

Hi so I've implemented a function that does a depth first search traversal of an undirected graph. But I am struggling to print the DFS traversal like the below output.

note: I have implemented my graph in a way so that the traversal would choose the neighbour node with the smallest value if a node has multiple adjacent neighbours.

the graph given is shown in the image and is my program and the start node is 0:

[image: graph]

the DFS traversal by my function would be:

```
1 > 2 > 3 > 2 > 4 > 5 > 4 > 6
```

But what I have prints out:

```
1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 > 6
```

Some nodes that are being revisited (when there is no choice but to visit them to go to the other unvisited ones) are not being printed.

below is my dfs function:

```
void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex) {
  struct node* adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
  struct node* temp = adjList;
  

  graph->visited[vertex] = 1;

  while (temp != NULL) {
    int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;
     
    if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {

        printf("node: %d\n", connectedVertex);
      DFS(graph, connectedVertex);
    }

    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
```

below is my full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int vertex;
  struct node* next;
};

struct node* createNode(int v);

struct Graph {
  int numVertices;
  int* visited;
  struct node** adjLists;
};


void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex) {
  struct node* adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
  struct node* temp = adjList;
  

  graph->visited[vertex] = 1;

  while (temp != NULL) {
    int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;
     
    if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {

        printf("node: %d\n", connectedVertex);
      DFS(graph, connectedVertex);
    }

    temp = temp->next;
  }
}


// Create a node
struct node* createNode(int v) {
  struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->vertex = v;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

// Create graph
struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices) {
  struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
  graph->numVertices = vertices;

  graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));

  graph->visited = malloc(vertices * sizeof(int));

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
    graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;
    graph->visited[i] = 0;
  }
  return graph;
}

void sortedInsert(struct node** head_ref,
                  struct node* new_node)
{
    struct node* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL
        || (*head_ref)->vertex
               >= new_node->vertex) {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
    else {
        /* Locate the node before 
the point of insertion */
        current = *head_ref;
        while (current->next != NULL
               && current->next->vertex < new_node->vertex) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}

// Add edge
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest) {
   
  // Add edge from src to dest
   sortedInsert(&graph->adjLists[src], createNode(dest));
  
  // Add edge from dest to src
     sortedInsert(&graph->adjLists[dest], createNode(src));
  
}

// Print the graph
void printGraph(struct Graph* graph) {
  int v;
  for (v = 0; v < graph->numVertices; v++) {
    struct node* temp = graph->adjLists[v];
    printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n ", v);
    while (temp) {
      printf("%d -> ", temp->vertex);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  struct Graph* graph = createGraph(7);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 1);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 3);
          
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2);
              
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3);

    addEdge(graph, 2, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 5);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 6);
    

  printGraph(graph);

  DFS(graph, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Push and pop all nodes you traverse into a stack, then print the contents of the stack?

Comment: *Why* do you think that should be the traversal?  The one you are printing is a valid traversal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not using a stack, this uses recursion

Comment: @ScottHunter some nodes that are being revisited (when there is no choice but to visit them to go to the other unvisited ones) are not being printed, that is my issue

Comment: You can still construct a stack while calling your functions recursively (heck, you *implicitly* create a stack using the function call *stack*, so once you have a finished solution return a value saying "okay caller, print your current info" or something like that).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am not sure how to change a recursive void function to a recursive function with a return value

Comment: Why should 0 be printed, when you only print nodes that get moved *to*?  And only nodes that have not been visited, at that?

Comment: Don't think of it as recursion, instead think of it like a normal function call (which it really is). That the `DFS` function is calling the `DFS` function doesn't make it any different from calling any function (like when the `main` function calls `createGraph` for example).

Comment: @ScottHunter apologies, that was a typo ill update my post without the 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah okay, where in the code should i place the return statement?

Comment: The simplest fix is probably to put `graph->visited[connectedVertex] = 1;` right after the `printf` in `DFS()`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that gives the output 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 > 6 > 3

Comment: Your overall design looks complicated to me – I'd rather store all data for a node ('visited' flag, adjacency list, etc) directly within the `node` struct. Within `graph` class you'd only keep the nodes themselves (array of: `struct node* nodes` and `graph->nodes = malloc(vertices * sizeof(*nodes);`). Adding adjacencies can then occur as `insertSorted(nodes+ x, nodes + y); insertSorted(nodes + y, nodes + x);` assuming `insertSorted` adds second argument to the adjacency list of first one. `next` would serve as that adjacency list and should be renamed then.

Comment: If interested: Partially worked out my proposition above (https://godbolt.org/z/1bT5Wv1xh) (some additional changes allowing less dynamic memory allocations); the adjacency list is replaced by a dynamic array (my personal preference, might come with some performance benefit as well), but you can easily turn that back into a linked list again (you'll need another struct for, so you'd have graph nodes and linked list nodes...). If you like, feel free to adopt, if not – never mind, have just been playing around with anyway ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua it is much simpler. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce the output you want:

```
int back = 0;  // = "We have already expanded vertex"

graph->visited[vertex] = 1;

while (temp != NULL) {
  int connectedVertex = temp->vertex;
 
  if (graph->visited[connectedVertex] == 0) {

    if ( back==1 ) // Report the revisited node 
      printf("node: %d\n", vertex);

    printf("node: %d\n", connectedVertex);
    DFS(graph, connectedVertex);
    back = 1; // Tag this node as having been expanded.
  } 

  temp = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to return the node that was moved to each time instead of printing them, where would i put the return statement?

Comment: This code isn't structured to allow that.  It can print multiple nodes within a single call to `DFS`, so which would you return?